# Explanation of Skolem's Paradox in Enderton's book

Tags: proof-explanation, first-order-logic, model-theory, paradoxes

In the book 'A Mathematical Introduction to Logic' by Enderton, he stated the Skolem's paradox at page $152:$

> Let $A_{ST}$ be your favourite set of axioms for set theory. We certainly hope these axioms are consistent. And so they have some model. By Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem, they have a countable model $\mathfrak{S}.$
>   Of course, $\mathfrak{S}$ is also a model of all the sentences logically implied by $A_{ST}.$
>   One of these sentences asserts that there are uncountable many sets.
>
> There is no contradiction here, but the situation here is sufficiently puzzling to be one called 'Skolem's Paradox'.
>   **It is true that in the structure $\mathfrak{S}$ there is no point that satisfies the formal definition of being a one-to-one map of the natural numbers onto the universe.
>   But this in no way excludes the possibility of there being (outside $\mathfrak{S}$) some genuine function providing such a one-to-one correspondence.**

I fail to understand the bold sentences.

From what I read online, the fact that  $\mathfrak{S}$ is countable is due to external viewing of $\mathfrak{S},$ that is, if we view universe of $\mathfrak{S}$ as a sub-universe, then we can find a bijection $f$ in the bigger universe between $\mathfrak{S}$ and set of natural numbers, and hence $\mathfrak{S}$ is countable.
By the way, $\mathfrak{S}$ does not know that it is countable. (WHY?)

Cantor's Theorem in Set Theory asserts the existence of uncountable set. 
So $\mathfrak{S}$ contains an uncountable set. 
However, being uncountable in $\mathfrak{S}$ does not mean it is uncountable in a bigger universe than universe of $\mathfrak{S},$ as there might be a bijection $g$ from a bigger universe between the uncountable set and set of natural numbers.

Is my thinking above correct? I still fail to grasp the essence of Skolem's Paradox not being a paradox.

Comment: To be *countable* according to the theory means that the theory proves the existence of a bijection. If the theory asserts that a certain set is uncountable, this means that the theory does **not** prove the existence of the necessary bijection.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: But how do we guarantee that the theory does not prove the existence of bijection? I am confused.

Comment: The theory $T$ proves Cantor's Th, asserting that there is a set (call it $A$) which is *uncountable*. Assuming that the theory is *consistent*, if the theory proves also that there is a *bijection* $f: A \to \mathbb N$, we have found a contradiction. Thus, if $T$ is consistent, it does not prove the existence of $f$.

Comment: But the topis has many interesting (and some controversial) issues; see e.g. [Skolem's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/).

Comment: Assuming that $T$ is consistent, it has a model: $\mathfrak{S}$. All theorems of $T$ are true in it; thus, in it there is a set $A$ such that  the theory does **not** "know" of any bijection in $\mathfrak{S}$.

Comment: Some readers may find my essay on Skolem's paradox helpful: https://www.infinitelymore.xyz/p/skolems-paradox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplyfying, the $\Bbb N$-in-your-structure and the $2^{\Bbb N}$-in-your-structure are countable in the "external" universe. I.e., there is a bijection $f:\Bbb N\hbox{-in-your-structure}\longrightarrow 2^{\Bbb N}\hbox{-in-your-structure}$, but your structure "ignores" the existence of $f$ because $f$ isn't a member of your structure.